# Why my string has diffrent length than i choosed?

Tags: c++

I want to create a string with numbers. So i define length of my string array to 10, but when i start the program in console is 11 chars.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 10

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int numArr[N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        numArr[i] = rand() % 26 + 97;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        std::cout << numArr[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    char str[N] = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        str[i] = numArr[i];

    std::cout << str << endl;
    std::cout << strlen(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use C-string functions like `strlen` or if you want to send a char array to `std::cout`, your string must be null-terminated, which it isn't. (A C string of length `N` requires `N + 1` chars.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string needs to be terminated with `\0` to get its length with `strlen`, in the code`str` isn't terminated with `\0`, when you add it as last character `strlen` gives correct answer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 10

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int numArr[N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        numArr[i] = rand() % 26 + 97;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        std::cout << numArr[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    char str[N + 1] = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        str[i] = numArr[i];

    str[N] = '\0'; // terminate with \0

    std::cout << str << endl;
    std::cout << strlen(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is rather risky to use char[N] when you can use std::string.
Here is safer way to write your code (and you will now get the 10 characters lenght you expect).

```
 int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    char numArr[N]; // I changed your type from int to char because you can only pack chars in a string

    for(char i = 0; i < N; i++)
        numArr[i] = (char)(rand() % 26 + 97);

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        std::cout << numArr[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::string str;
    str.reserve(N); // not strictly required: this is an optimization
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        str.push_back(numArr[i]);

    std::cout << str << endl;
    std::cout << str.length();
    return 0;
}
```